# How to create a custom keyboard in android with tamil fonts?

Tags: android, custom-keyboard, tamil

For my project i need to create a keyboard with tamil fonts.I got some information in google like keycodes. but not clear

Sample output:
output: "பே"

for the above letter i need to press two keys("ப"and"ே"), so how can i detect which keys are pressed and how can i replace it.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

[Your can start building custom keyboard according this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615)

And replace eg.

```
<key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9"/>
```

with

```
<Key android:keyOutputText="பே"  android:keyLabel="பே"/>
```

Or try to find correct keycode for you output

I tried it with `android:keyOutputText` and works for me.